# Why is there a significant fluctuation in audio amplitude at the beginning of recording?

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am using PyAudio to record my speaker output, write it to a WAV file, and then plot the sound wave from that file. Here's my code:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 10
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stereo_mix_name = 'Stereo Mix'
info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
stereo_mix = None

# Find Stereo Mix device
for i in range(0, numdevices):
    device_info = p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i)
    if (device_info.get('maxInputChannels')) > 0 and stereo_mix_name in device_info.get('name'):
        stereo_mix = device_info
        break

stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
                channels = CHANNELS,
                rate = RATE,
                input = True,
                input_device_index = stereo_mix.get('index'),
                frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)

frames = []
current_index = 0
audio = np.zeros([CHUNK * 20,], dtype=np.int16)

try:
    while True:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

# save as WAV file
wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()

# read the output
wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'rb')
sample_freq = wf.getframerate()
n_samples = wf.getnframes()
t_audio = n_samples / sample_freq
signal_wave = wf.readframes(n_samples)
signal_array = np.frombuffer(signal_wave, dtype=np.int16)
times = np.linspace(0, n_samples / sample_freq, num = n_samples * 2)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.plot(times, signal_array)
plt.title('WAV File')
plt.ylabel('Signal Value')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.xlim(0, t_audio)
plt.show()
```

I've tried recording when something is not playing (and also during playback, but no playback is a clearer situation) and there is a random fluctuation of amplitude right when the audio is first being recorded. It looks like this.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone know why this might be? I'm on a Windows laptop using the Stereo Mix recording device.

Comment: This often happens for reasons that go into hardware design and thus aren't on-topic here at all. Have you considered just throwing out the first N samples?

Comment: Yeah that was a consideration I had. I was curious and wanted a clarification on whether it would be a hardware/software issue on my end before I did anything else. Do you have any explanation or links online explaining why this might be on the hardware level?